# Rollback to a specific migration

Tags: entity-framework

What are the steps for rolling  back to specific migration state.

I want to remove the field Url....so I ran the command below.

> Update-Database –TargetMigration: AddUrl

The column name on the db table was successfully removed but it was added back when I ran the application.

Do I manually remove the `'201504212002469_AddUrl'` file under the `Migrations` folder and everything else that was added?

Comment: Did you remove the field from your model?

Comment: Forgot to do that. After removing all the of its references its working now. 
Is it safe to remove the '201504212002469_AddUrl.cs' file?

Comment: Yeah, I'm always removing migrations or rolling multiple migrations into a single migration. Remember to delete the corresponding record from the __MigrationHistory table as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to delete any records from __MigrationHistory.

Just roll back to your previous migration. So if you have two migrations:

```
201504212002468_Something
201504212002469_AddUrl
```

Run

```
Update-Database --TargetMigration:Something
```

After that you can remove 201504212002469_AddUrl.cs and other related files from the project.

Comment: That worked. Thank you. I removed the record from the __MigrationHistory table as well and it looks like it didn't affect anything. So I guess it doesn't matter. Removing it will keep it clean.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the [automatic update to latest migrations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591621.aspx#initializer) by removing the `MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion` initializer, example:

```
   Database.SetInitializer(
       new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<BlogContext, Configuration>())
```